# Javascript 2d plotting libraries

Tags: javascript, plot

So I've been working on a project that requires offering the possibility to view the results of a simulation in 2D. Now the solution that was first considered was [RGraph](http://www.rgraph.net/). However it seems that now the fact that RGraph's free license requires a link to their page is not in agreement with the client and we need to find some free alternatives.

Now I'm starting to look at [JIT](http://thejit.org/) and [Google Chart Tools](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/) but I'm not sure yet either if their license is better that the one of RGraph, or how difficult it would be to make the actual changes.

So basically I would like to know if you have any other javascript libraries that fit the needs (being capable of plotting a 2d array for example and having a free license) or if you have any reason why I should dismiss one of the two libraries I proposed to look at, that would also save me some time.

Thanks,
Bogdan

Comment: http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/css/top-jquery-chart-libraries-interactive-charts/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try flot

http://code.google.com/p/flot/

Answer (score 0):

[Ext JS 4](http://www.sencha.com/products/extjs/examples/#sample-3) offers a variety of chart types.